# incorrect value in array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this code, but i can't understand why `var_dump($jobs[0][0])` return `Some Director`, but when i do `value='.$jobs[$i][0].'` i simply get the first word, in this case only "`Some`". The question is why ? The same occurs in the others inputs.

thanks

```
<form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($jobs); $i++) {
        $u = $i+1;
        echo '
        <div class ="empregadores" id="input_'.$u.'" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <input placeholder="Cargo" name="myformdata[role][]" type="text" value='.$jobs[$i][0].' > 
            <input placeholder="Empregador" name="myformdata[company][]" type="text" value='.$jobs[$i][1].' >
            <input placeholder="Função" name="myformdata[role_function][]" type="text" value='.$jobs[$i][2].' >
        </div>';
    }

    ?>
    </form>
```

**var_dump($jobs);**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'Some Director'
      1 => string 'some company' 
      2 => string 'some text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not enclosed the values in double quotes inside the `value=` attributes.  Add opening and closing quotes, as in: `value="'.$jobs[$i][0].'"`

```
    echo '
    <div class ="empregadores" id="input_'.$u.'" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <input placeholder="Cargo" name="myformdata[role][]" type="text" value="'.$jobs[$i][0].'" > 
        <input placeholder="Empregador" name="myformdata[company][]" type="text" value="'.$jobs[$i][1].'" >
        <input placeholder="Função" name="myformdata[role_function][]" type="text" value="'.$jobs[$i][2].'" >
    </div>';
```

Without the quotes, the HTML looks like `value=Some director`. The value ends at the first whitespace if not enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the HTML attribute in double-quotes. For example, change this:

```
... type="text" value='.$jobs[$i][0].' >
```

to this:

```
... type="text" value="'.$jobs[$i][0].'" >
```